# Split page in two contents which are independent of each other

Tags: multicol, tcolorbox

> I would like to compare two exams so I'm trying to split page in two contents which are independent of each other to show the differences between 2014 Exam VS 2015. For this reason, I wrote the following code but I can go further than that any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry}

\tcbset{
    lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=0pt, 
                       fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,  
                       colbacktitle=white, coltitle=DarkOliveGreen,    
                       top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                       boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                       attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/3, 
                                                                                                            xshift=-2mm}%
                      },
}

\newtcbtheorem{myLemma1}{Exercise}{lemmastyle}{thm}


\tcbset{
    lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=0pt, 
                       fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,  
                       colbacktitle=white, coltitle=DarkOliveGreen,    
                       top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                       boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                       attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/3, 
                                                                                                            xshift=-2mm}%
                      },
}

\newtcbtheorem{myLemma2}{Exercise}{lemmastyle}{thm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\shadowbox{
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{description}
\item[The differences between 2014 Exam VS 2015  :] 
\end{description}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{center}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{description}
\item[Exam 1:] 
\end{description}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{description}
\item[Exam 2:] 
\end{description}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a task for `tcbraster`. And why are you using `shadowbox` when you have the full power of `tcolorbox` at hand?;-)

Comment: i didn't notice that i can use tcolorbox instead of shadowbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The request looks like suited for `tcbraster` - feature of `tcolorbox`.

Please have a look into `tcolorbox` documentation for more configuration options.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,footnotesep=0.5cm]{geometry}

\tcbset{
    lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=0pt, 
                       fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,  
                       colbacktitle=white, coltitle=DarkOliveGreen,    
                       top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                       boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                       attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/3, 
                                                                                                            xshift=-2mm}%
                      },
}

\newtcbtheorem{myLemma1}{Exercise}{lemmastyle}{thm}


\tcbset{
    lemmastyle/.style={enhanced, colback=white, colframe=blue!20, arc=0pt, 
                       fonttitle=\bfseries, description color=Maroon,  
                       colbacktitle=white, coltitle=DarkOliveGreen,    
                       top=\tcboxedtitleheight,
                       boxed title style={arc=0pt},
                       attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/3, 
                                                                                                            xshift=-2mm}%
                      },
}

\newtcbtheorem{myLemma2}{Exercise}{lemmastyle}{thm}

\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[before={\begin{center}},after={\end{center}},width=0.5\textwidth,enhanced jigsaw,drop shadow,halign=center,valign=center,colback=white!40!yellow,sharp corners]
The differences between 2014 Exam VS 2015 
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height=rows,raster valign=top,raster column skip=5mm]

\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
Foo
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}
\begin{myLemma1}{}{}
\end{myLemma1}
\begin{myLemma2}{}{}
\end{myLemma2}

\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Educ: Happy TeXing!