# using tcbraster to split page

Tags: tcolorbox, split

I would like to split my document using  'tcbraster' but it doesn't work

- I mean by split page something like what you did @Christian Hupfer   in this post 
  [Split page in two contents which are independent of each other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283651/split-page-in-two-contents-which-are-independent-of-each-other)
- i try to reduce my code :

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
  \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage[french]{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
  \newcommand{\centerbox}[1]% #1 = text
  {\bgroup% use local definitions
    \parskip=0pt
    \sbox0{\fbox{#1}}
    \dimen0=\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 0.5\wd0\relax
    \par\noindent\rule{\dimen0}{0.8pt}\box0\rule{\dimen0}{0.8pt}\par
  \egroup}

  \usepackage{xhfill}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  %\usepackage{xcolor}
  %\usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
  %\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}
  \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}
    \tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, thick, text centered, minimum height=3em}}
    \tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}

  \newlength\TextBoxWd% width of the text boxes
  \newlength\TextBoxSep% separation of the text boxes
  \newlength\TextBoxHt% height of the text boxes

  \setlength\TextBoxWd{\marginparwidth}
  \setlength\TextBoxSep{\marginparsep}
  \setlength\TextBoxHt{2cm}

  \newcommand\ThickTitleRule{\xrfill[0.5ex]{3pt}}

  \newcommand\Title[4]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
    \par
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
     % \fbox{\parbox[t][\TextBoxHt][c]{\TextBoxWd}{\raggedright#3}}\hspace{\TextBoxSep}%
      \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
        \leavevmode
        \centering
        \ThickTitleRule\quad{\scshape\bfseries\itshape#1}\quad\ThickTitleRule\par
        \vskip-0.2\baselineskip
        \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par\vskip-.8\baselineskip% Thick horizontal line
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%Thin horizontal line
        \par\vskip0.75ex
        {\Large\scshape\bfseries\itshape#2\par}% Title
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par\par\vskip-.7\baselineskip% Thin horizontal line
        \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}% Thick horizontal line
      }%
     % \hspace{\TextBoxSep}\fbox{\parbox[t][\TextBoxHt][c]{\TextBoxWd}{\raggedright#4}}\par%
    }%
    \vskip\baselineskip
  \endgroup
  }

  \begin{document}

  \Title{Mohcine}{Educ}{}{}
  \bigskip

  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.8pt}

  \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height=rows,raster valign=top,raster column skip=5mm]

  \centerbox{Exercice 1}%
  Soient $a$ et $b$ deux ombres réels non nuls. Montrer que :
  \[3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge 2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)\]

  \centerbox{Solution de l'exercice 1}
  \subsection*{\fbox{Méthode 1}}
       \begin{description}
      \item[]
      \end{description}
      Soit $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^*$

      Posons $t=\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}$ , on a :
      \[
        \begin{aligned}
           & 3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge
           2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right) \\
           \iff &
          3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}-2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right) \geq 0\\
          \iff  & t^{2}-2t+1\geq 0\\
          \iff & \left(t-1\right)^{2}\geq 0
        \end{aligned}
      \]
      comme on a $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}\quad (t-1)^{2}\geq 0$ une
      proposition vraie alors la proposition
      \[
        \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}^*\quad
        3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge
        2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)
      \]
      est vraie
          \centerbox{Exercice 2}%
  Bla Bla Bla 
  \centerbox{Solution de l'exercice 2}
  Bla bla bla
  \end{tcbraster}

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Don't use `$$...$$`, that's deprecated. Use `\[...\]` instead. Your document does not compile

Comment: The main problem is here, that `tcbraster` does work only if `tcbox` commands or `tcolorbox` environments are used inside the raster environment. This is apparently not the case!

Comment: could you please come up with solution to this problem

Comment: Please clearify:  1st.) What does 'split' actually mean here and 2nd: Reduce your example to the absolute minimum here -- the watermark etc. other stuff are not needed, in my point of view

Answer (score 3):

Here is a preliminary solution. I didn't weed out all the unnecessary stuff. As @ChrstianHupref remarked, the `tcbraster` environment must contain only `tcolorbox` or related (not even `\par` or empty lines!). By the way, it says solution to exercice 2, which should be one. You should use a proper counter with `\label` and `\ref` instead.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
% \newcommand{\centerbox}[1]% #1 = text
% {\bgroup% use local definitions
%   \parskip=0pt
%   \sbox0{\fbox{#1}}
%   \dimen0=\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 0.5\wd0\relax
%   \par\noindent\rule{\dimen0}{0.8pt}\box0\rule{\dimen0}{0.8pt}\par
% \egroup}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse,raster}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}
  \tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, thick, text centered, minimum height=3em}}
  \tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}

\newlength\TextBoxWd% width of the text boxes
\newlength\TextBoxSep% separation of the text boxes
\newlength\TextBoxHt% height of the text boxes

\setlength\TextBoxWd{\marginparwidth}
\setlength\TextBoxSep{\marginparsep}
\setlength\TextBoxHt{2cm}

\newcommand\ThickTitleRule{\xrfill[0.5ex]{3pt}}

\newcommand\Title[4]{%
\begingroup
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
  \par
  \makebox[\linewidth]{%
   % \fbox{\parbox[t][\TextBoxHt][c]{\TextBoxWd}{\raggedright#3}}\hspace{\TextBoxSep}%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
      \leavevmode
      \centering
      \ThickTitleRule\quad{\scshape\bfseries\itshape#1}\quad\ThickTitleRule\par
      \vskip-0.2\baselineskip
      \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par\vskip-.8\baselineskip% Thick horizontal line
      \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%Thin horizontal line
      \par\vskip0.75ex
      {\Large\scshape\bfseries\itshape#2\par}% Title
      \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par\par\vskip-.7\baselineskip% Thin horizontal line
      \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}% Thick horizontal line
    }%
   % \hspace{\TextBoxSep}\fbox{\parbox[t][\TextBoxHt][c]{\TextBoxWd}{\raggedright#4}}\par%
  }%
  \vskip\baselineskip
\endgroup
}

\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
%\usepackage{xcolor}


\newwatermark[allpages,color= magenta!30,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{Mohcine }

\newtcolorbox{centerbox}[2][]{colback=white, colframe=black!75,fonttitle=\normalfont,
  colbacktitle=white, coltitle=black,
  enhanced, attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-3mm},
  title=#2,#1}

%========================================================================================
\begin{document}

\Title{Mohcine}{Educ}{}{}
\bigskip
%\begin{LTR}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.8pt}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height=rows,raster valign=top]%,raster column skip=5mm]
%
  \begin{centerbox}{Exercice 1}%
    Soient $a$ et $b$ deux ombres réels non nuls. Montrer que :
    \[
      3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge
      2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)
    \]
  \end{centerbox}
 % 
  \begin{centerbox}{Solution de l'exercice 2}
    \subsection*{\fbox{Méthode 1}}
    \begin{description}
    \item[]
    \end{description}
    Soit $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^*$

    Posons $t=\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}$ , on a :
    \[
      \begin{aligned}
         & 3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge
         2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right) \\
         \iff &
        3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}-2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right) \geq 0\\
        \iff  & t^{2}-2t+1\geq 0\\
        \iff & \left(t-1\right)^{2}\geq 0
      \end{aligned}
    \]
    comme on a $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}\quad (t-1)^{2}\geq 0$ une
    proposition vraie alors la proposition
    \[
      \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}^*\quad
      3+\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}\ge
      2\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}\right)
    \]
    est vraie
  \end{centerbox}
%
  \begin{centerbox}{Exercice 2}%
    \subsection*{\fbox{Méthode 2}}
\end{centerbox}
\end{tcbraster}
%\end{LTR}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any possible to make box be fexlible for example box of exercise 1 be fit of what inside it and follow strictly by solution of exercise 2 not to be in right side insetad should be in right other exercise

Comment: Then it would no longer be a raster, if I understand you correctly. You can look at the `varwidth` options of `tcolorbox`.